# Calling a public method from another class

Tags: c#

In c# is there a way to call a public method from another class without instantiating an instance of it?

```
class ClassA{

   public void callMe(){
      //something...
   } 

} 

class ClassB{

   public void WannaCallYou(){
      //here I want to call ClassA's callMe()
   } 

}
```

Comment: Make it static. It's probably not the right way of doing what you're doing, unless it's some kind of stateless helper method.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but I  cant make it static. I wonder if there is a way without using static

Comment: @Matahari: Any specific reasons for not using static? what is your actual requirement?

Comment: You need a reference to `ClassA` in order to access its methods. BTW, please use standard naming conventions and PascalCase the method `callMe()` into `CallMe()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use static keyword

```
public class ClassA
{
   public static void CallMe(){
   }
}

public class ClassB
{
   public void WannaCallYou(){
       ClassA.CallMe();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassA
{
    static ClassA singleton = null;

    public static ClassA GetInstance()
    {
        if (singleton == null)
            singleton = new ClassA();
        return singleton;
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
   public void WannaCallYou()
   {
       ClassA.GetInstance().callMe();
   }
}
```

If you can not make it static, you can try to do it in this way.
Instantiating a static ClassA, and get it be calling GetInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void CallMe();
}

public class ClassB
{
    public void WannaCallYou(ClassA a)
    {
        a.CallMe();
    }
}
```

or do you want to use a private field?

```
public class ClassB
{
    private ClassA a;
    public ClassB(ClassA a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void WannaCallYou()
    {
        a.CallMe();
    }
}
```

---

A fundamental concept of object oriented programming is encapsulation. A class should encapsulate not only the data to describe the object, but also *all* the methods needed to act upon the data. Think of a class as a briefcase that contains not only papers (the data) but also pencils and erasers and rulers and anything else you need (the methods) to fill the papers with data.

So in your case to call the method `CallMe()` blindly without first getting a briefcase (an instance of `ClassA`) is against the rules. Once you have a reference to `ClassA` then it becomes trivial to call its methods, or read its data.